# Breeze ODataException without $expand option

Tags: c#, breeze, asp.net-web-api2

We are two developers (one with Windows Server 2008 R2 and the other with Windows 8) that working on same project (on TFS with Visual Studio 2013 and with the last nuget packages like Breeze 1.4.11 installed), but with different results on breeze query execution.

With Windows Server 2008 R2 we must add `$expand` option otherwise we have an error

```
Only properties specified in $expand can be traversed in $select query options
```

, conversely with Windows 8 the query run successfully without `$expand` option, why?

query with`$expand`:

```
/breeze/breeze/Udc_Testata?$filter=Id_Tipo_Udc eq 'A'&$orderby=Id_Udc&$top=100&$expand=FK_Udc_Testata_Tipo_Udc%2CFK_Udc_Posizione_Udc_Testata%2FFK_Udc_Posizione_Partizioni&$select=Codice_Udc%2CFK_Udc_Testata_Tipo_Udc%2FDescrizione%2CFK_Udc_Posizione_Udc_Testata%2FFK_Udc_Posizione_Partizioni%2FDescrizione&$inlinecount=allpages
```

query without `$expand`:

```
/breeze/breeze/Udc_Testata?$filter=Id_Tipo_Udc eq 'A'&$orderby=Id_Udc&$top=100&$select=Codice_Udc%2CFK_Udc_Testata_Tipo_Udc%2FDescrizione%2CFK_Udc_Posizione_Udc_Testata%2FFK_Udc_Posizione_Partizioni%2FDescrizione&$inlinecount=allpages
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Standard OData queries require the $expand option. However, if you decorate your Breeze ApiController with the BreezeControllerAttribute, Breeze will understand the query even if you don't specify the $expand.

So it sounds like the Windows Server 2008 R2 doesn't have a 'Breeze friendly' controller.