# Related property projection error in BreezeJS

Tags: breeze

In the BreezeJS documentation http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/projection-queries they describe how to perform a projection on Related Property and it works fine on my developing environment.

```
var query = EntityQuery.from("Orders")
    .where("Freight", FilterQueryOp.GreaterThan, 500)
    .select("Customer.CompanyName")
    .orderBy("Customer.CompanyName");
```

But if i publish the application when i run the query i get the error:

```
Only properties specified in $expand can be traversed in $select query options
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an OData restriction when using the OData provider, ( it does not occur with the standard WebApi provider), but in any event you can get around it by adding

```
.expand("Customer")
```

to your query.

Comment: Thx Jay, but i decorated the controller with the [BreezeController] attribute, it shouldn't raise this error, am i wrong ? If i use the expand the entire entity would be inserted into the object graph, i want only get a plain object with only the properties specified into the projection.

Comment: And same happens here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23268072/breeze-odataexception-without-expand-option

Comment: Are you adding the `[BreezeController]` attribute to an ASP.NET Web API OData controller? In that case, the OData controller may trump your efforts to bend the API to the Breeze way.

Comment: NO, that's the strange thing: It's a Web API 2 standard controller.

Comment: No any additional suggestion ?